# Converting Gmail contents to Word

Tags: microsoft-word, gmail

I would like to move by many of my Gmail messages into a Word document. I have been copying and pasting one at a time; but I have thousands of emails to convert; so this has been laborious. Can you help?

Comment: Please tell us more about why you're doing this. It will help identify the best tool(s) for you.

Comment: What @DougHarris said.  I cannot think of any good reason to move them into a WORD document.  What is it you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What platform are you using, Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to download the email using IMAP or POP into a desktop email client (e.g. Outlook, Thunderbird, Apple Mail). See [instructions from The Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/gmail).

Once the email is in your desktop email program, there will be other options.

Answer (score 2):

You can export and convert your Gmail messages to RTF with [MsgExtract](http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/). You only need to select the Gmail folders that you want to export messages from and MailExporter will save them as RTF or if you prefer as HTML.

(Disclaimer, I am the author of MsgExtract)